# Debugging Not Working in VS2015 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have a fresh VS2015 installation on a recently (auto-)upgraded Windows 10 machine. I generated my solution files using CMake.

Whenever I try to debug my native C++ code, I get the "Break Mode" saying "The application is in break mode", *"Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)."*:

[image]

When I click "Continue execution" the debug session just closes.

What can I do to start debugging?

Another problem that I noticed, which may or may not be related, is that every time, after opening VS2015, and trying to run or debug a program for the first time since opening, I get the following error dialog:

[image]

Once I click OK it does not com back until I restart VS2015.
Reinstallation did not remove the problem.

Comment: Do "normal" projects work and is it only related to CMake?

Comment: @Thomas: good question. As I said a fresh install. I'll check...

Comment: @Thomas: A normal project does not work either. I don't think this is CMake related.

Comment: Have you tried changing your debug engine?

Comment: How do I  do that? This is a new vanilla installation.